# putting new column to record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have wrote query to calculate TOTAL WORK TIME and Overtime of an employee based on Intime and outTime but can't figure out to put another column 'IsAbsent'. e.g. if person doesn't come on any specific date than his record will not be present for that specific date so then new column IsAbsent should contain ABSENT otherwise Present.

Query:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else '00:00' end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

[image]

Comment: You are doing `inner join` thus you will never get records when person is not clocked in

Answer (score 0):

I've a bit trouble with reading your tables... but lets assume we have two tables: 
employee and time... you'll need to do a left join:

```
 select e.*, t.* 
 from employee e 
     left join time t on e.employee_id = t.employee_id
```

When t.employee_id is null then you'll have no time record... so let's build that in:

```
 select e.*
      IsAbsent = case 
                     when t.employee_id is null then 'ABSENT' 
                     else 'PRESENT' 
                 end 
 from employee e 
     left join time t on e.employee_id = t.employee_id
```

next step will be probably put a constraint on the time table (everything from 2014 for example), so let's build that in:

```
 select e.*,
      IsAbsent = case 
                     when t.employee_id is null then 'ABSENT' 
                     else 'PRESENT' 
                 end 
 from employee e 
     left join time t on e.employee_id = t.employee_id and 
                datepart(y, t.timestamp) = 2014
```

notice that I've put the constraint in the join, that's vital.

does this makes sense?